# PHP: Retrieving the HTTP response headers that comes along with the $_POST

Tags: php

Here is my situation. I have a PHP script in my own server. The purpose is to receive $_POST values from another server. Retrieving these $_POST values are simple. But the remote server includes an additional HTTP header with the sent $_POST request that my server needs to retrieve.

The question is how I can grab this HTTP header? The flow goes like this:

Remote server -- > send POST along with HTTP header --- > My server (retrieves POST and HTTP headers) -- > Do additional processing

Probably this is very easy and I'm missing something I already know. But I tried any possibilities like cURL, $_SERVER variables but could not find one. Thanks for the help.

**UPDATE:** I would like to retrieve the X-Mandrill-Signature header sent by Mandrill in authenticating web hook request. You can read it here: http://help.mandrill.com/entries/23704122-Authenticating-webhook-requests

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any and all received HTTP headers will be in `$_SERVER['HTTP_*']`, e.g. `$_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE']` for the `Content-Type` header. It *may* get singled out into a different key, authentication headers typically don't have an `HTTP_` prefix for instance.

Comment: Yes I tried this one and it does not work: $_SERVER['HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE'] While it retrieves the posted values correctly with this $_POST['posted_parameter']. According to Mandrill: http://help.mandrill.com/entries/23704122-Authenticating-webhook-requests. They provide additional HTTP headers called "X-Mandrill-Signature". I am not sure how to retrieve this. Thanks for the tip.

Comment: If you don't receive a `Content-Type` header then `HTTP_CONTENT_TYPE` obviously doesn't work, that was just an example. Have you tried `$_SERVER['HTTP_X_MANDRILL_SIGNATURE']`? Have you tried `var_dump($_SERVER)` to see what you get exactly?

Comment: Great thanks Deceze! It's working now. This is the one: $_SERVER['HTTP_X_MANDRILL_SIGNATURE']